# Do I need to use a .build file, or can I just call msbuild and pass a configuration name?

Tags: build, msbuild, teamcity, build-automation

I'm trying to automate my build process with TeamCity.  Some tutorials tell me I need to set up a `.build` script to do stuff, but it looks like TeamCity can already do all that stuff.  Can't I just call `MsBuild` and pass in the target solution/project and specify a configuration name and publish profile name?  What's so special about a `.build` file?

Comment: Have you tried it? Yes, you can just tell TC the solution file path and what targets to build.

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity uses what they call "Runners." There are a dozen already configured, one of which is the Visual Studio runner, and that will allow you to build a Visual Studio solution. The difference between a build file and TeamCity runners is that you have to configure the runners through the interface (or the API) while a complicated build you can craft through a single build script. It's a matter of preference.